# How to publish multiple Fitnesse result reports in one Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, fitnesse

I set up one Jenkins job to run two Fitnesse tests at the build section:

[image]

Therefore I have two result files:

- /data/test-automation/FitNesseResults/Home.Test1/results.xml
- /data/test-automation/FitNesseResults/Home.Test2/results.xml

The job is working fine, but I can't publish the results of both FitNesse tests at the Post Build Actions section:

[image]

It only provides one input field. I have heard it should be possible to specify two result files with an ant pattern, but haven't found an example.
How can I publish both result xmls?

Comment: Is using the Jenkins plugin a requirement? I tend to use the jUnit runner, which produces results in surefire XML format (which Jenkins can parse and can easily grab from 2 locations) and HTML. To combine the HTML results from two runs I create a small command line tool (which you could include in a Maven build to run after the tests have completed).

Comment: @FriedHoeben The Jenkins plugin is not an requirement. What is your command line tool doing? Appending one file to the other one?

Comment: It creates an overview of HTML reports generated by multiple runs: highlights failures in each run, generates a list of tests ordered by execution time and adds some graphs: how tests are distributed across suites, how much time each suite takes, relative time used by each test. A screenshot can be seen in https://github.com/unclebob/fitnesse/issues/806#issuecomment-470587494 (or while it still exists: https://gitlab.com/hsac-fitnesse/sample-pipeline-fitnesse-tests/-/jobs/352794483/artifacts/file/test-results/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a file pattern like results*.xml

In your example you can store your test results like:

```
data/test-automation/FitNesseResults/HomeTest1.results.xml

data/test-automation/FitNesseResults/HomeTest2.results.xml
```

And you set the "Publish Fitnesse results report" to:

```
/data/test-automation/FitNesseResults/*.results.xml
```